# Does any isomorphism of splitting fields automatically fix the base field?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I was wondering whether it's true that if $L_1,L_2$ are splitting fields of $f\in \Bbbk[x]$ over $\Bbbk$ then any isomorphism between them as fields must fix $\Bbbk$. If this is true, why? Is there any intuition to be had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For example, let $L_1=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]2,i)$ be the splitting field of $f(X) = X^4-2$ over $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)$. Let $\sigma$ be the automorphism of $L_1$ which sends $\sqrt[4]2\mapsto i\sqrt[4]2$ and fixes everything else.

Then $\sigma(L_1)$ is isomorphic to $L_1$ and is another splitting field of $f$ over $K$. But $\sigma$ does not even reduce to an automorphism of $K$, whilst $\sigma^2$ reduces to a non-trivial automorphism.

Comment: Okay, then I'm confused about Theorem 4 [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/splittingisom.pdf). Why is the correspondence with the maximal ideals particularly interesting if we don't fix the base field? I mean, doesn't this miss the point of Galois theory?

Comment: The maximal ideals are of $L_1\otimes_K L_2$, so $K$ comes into both sides of the equivalence. Specifically, in this case, $L_1\otimes_\mathbb Q L_2\not\cong L_1\otimes_K L_2$.